# how to get the values from table which contains key value pair structure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the below structure  i want to get the name and address values based on id value.

i tried with below  query but it didn't work.

```
select name,address from details where c_id=111
table name=**details**

c_id   key    value
111    name   abc
111    email  add@gmail.com
111    address  h.no 22,hyderabad
222    name    raj
222    email   xyz@yahoo.com
222    address h.no 24,india
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subqueries to get result sets for names and addresses, and then join them:

```
SELECT name, address
FROM   (SELECT c_id, value AS name
        FROM   details
        WHERE  key = 'name') n
JOIN   (SELECT c_id, value AS address
        FROM   details
        WHERE  key = 'address') a ON n.c_id = a.c_id
```

Comment: i am getting this error, ORA-00904 "value " invalid identifier

Comment: `value` is a reserved keyword in Oracle, you need to surround it with braces try: `"value"` or `"VALUE"` or `"VaLuE"` The name within braces is case sensitive, you must check how it has been created (tip: DESC tablename)

Comment: run `DESC details` and you will see whether the column name is `VALUE` or `value` or `Value` or `VaLue` or `vAluE` or anything else. The column name is case sensitive, no one has access to your database and no one can guess how it has been created.

Comment: its working now. i have another column named "email".can you tell me how to get name, address,and email